# Cannot view tiff images in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, tiff

**problem** 
I am able to load pictures with the `Image()` module in kivy. But for some reason, I can't load .tif files into kivy. When the image source is `'..\pics\lugia.png'`, the image loads perfectly fine. But if the source is `'..\pics\snorlax.tif'`, I just get that white box and the error:

```
[WARNING] [Image       ] Unable to load image <C:\Users\path\pics\snorlax.tif>
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading texture ..\pics\snorlax.tif
```

**code**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class ContainerBox(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ContainerBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = 'vertical'
        #self.picture = Image(allow_stretch=True, source='..\pics\lugia.png')
        self.picture = Image(allow_stretch=True, source='..\pics\snorlax.tif')
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.add_widget(self.picture), timeout=0.1)


class SimpleImage(App):
    def build(self):
        return ContainerBox()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SimpleImage().run()
```

**technical details**

- The images are from [veekun.com](https://veekun.com/dex/downloads) (property of nintendo etc).
- All the images are 64 x 64. I just exported some of them into TIFF format. So image size shouldn't be the problem.
- I am using Kivy version 1.11.0rc1
- According to Anaconda, the virtual environment is running Python 3.5.6
- I am running this via PyCharm on Windows 7
- I have sdl2_image version 2.0.2 build 0. According to the sdl2_image page, sdl2_image has supported tiff since version 1.2.5.
- I have libtiff version 4.0.9
- changing the file extension from '.tif' to '.tiff'

**my question to you** 
Am I doing something wrong, or does Kivy just not support TIFF format?

Comment: Probably whatever image loader you're using doesn't support tiff, or at least doesn't have tiff support enabled.

Comment: It looks like the sdl2_image image provider can support tiff, so probably either you are not using that or (as above) it doesn't have that support enabled.

Comment: How do I even find out what image loader I'm using?

Comment: It should be printed in the log.

Comment: The log shows `[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)`. I assume those are my image providers. How do I add one that supports tiff?

Comment: I have sdl2_image version 2.0.2 build 0. According to [the sdl2_image page](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/), sdl2_image has supported tiff since version 1.2.5.

Comment: @FergusWyrm share the tiff

Comment: @eyllanesc here's [snorlax.tif](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14wkJzDo3HpSB2Dyx2JzNmbGjY0vcwq57/view) and [salamence.tiff](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NwpeXF3SIILNbAHy6VNIyhfXXHJm5HWU/view). Both pictures result in the same error. CCITT_1.TIF from [this site](https://www.fileformat.info/format/tiff/sample/index.htm) doesn't work either.

Comment: I am able to load both (*tif(f)*) files using your code (after a few warning message boxes pop up), while *CCITT\_1* works fine. *Python 3.7.3* and *Kivy 1.10.1* (*sdl* (*kivy.deps.sdl2 0.1.18*) and all dependencies installed by *pip*, as instructed in the *Kivy* web page) on *Win*. I noticed you're using a *rc\** version. You should upgrade to an official released one. Also, double the *bkslash*es in paths (`source='..\\pics\\snorlax.tif'`), or use *raw* strings (not the root cause here, but it might generate problems).

Comment: This works for me also on Mac, Providers: img_tex, img_imageio, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored) and sdl2 was used.

Comment: @CristiFati It sounds like my wonky installation is to blame for this. I've been trying to use anaconda to keep all installations in virtual environments.

Comment: Can't reproduce your bug. Using: Python 3.5.1 on OSX, Kivy 1.11.1. Providers: img_tex, img_imageio, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored). Using *pip* on a virtualenv. The window shows snorlax correctly.

Comment: I made a new python virtual environment with venv, installed kivy following the official guide, and got it running. It can view tiff files now (although I'm getting `TIFFReadDirectory` Warnings, but that's a separate issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to create a proper installation**
I used anaconda to install kivy and I wasn't very thorough with installing the dependencies properly. So I had to create a fresh virtual python installation.

Note:
This is for python version 3.5 or higher.
Also I am going to have you explicitly state what python installation is going to be creating this environment. To my knowledge, there's no good reason to do this.

**Windows**

1. (optional) find where python is installed for you.
   Start windows command prompt.
   C:\Users\H>`python`
   `import sys, os`
   `os.path.dirname(sys.executable)`
   C:\Users\H\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36
   therefore, my python installation is at
   C:\Users\H\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python
2. Prepare a place for your new virtual environment.
   I created a folder called "venvs" in my home directory.
   C:\Users\H\venvs
3. Create new virtual environment. I'll name mine "env1".
   Start windows command prompt.
   if you did step 1
   C:\Users\H>`C:\Users\H\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python -m venv C:\Users\H\venvs\env1`
   if you did not do step 1
   C:\Users\H>`python -m venv C:\Users\H\venvs\env1`
4. Activate the new virtual environment
   C:\Users\H>`C:\Users\H\venvs\env1\Scripts\activate`
5. Install dependencies
   (env1) C:\Users\H>`python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy_deps.sdl2==0.1.22 kivy_deps.glew==0.1.12`
6. Install kivy
   (env1) C:\Users\H>`python -m pip install kivy==1.11.1`
7. PyCharm
   If you're using PyCharm, go to File>Settings
   From the settings menu Project>Project Interpreter
   Click the gear>Add
   In the Add Python Interpreter menu select 'Existing environment', then set the interpreter to the location of your new virtual environment.
   Mine was C:\Users\H\venvs\env1\Scripts\python.exe. 
   Click Okay.
   Hit Apply in the settings menu. Once you hit okay, your script should be able to view TIFF files.