# PyQt5: TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag XXXXX (0xYYYY) encountered

Tags: python, pyqt5, warnings, geotiff

I have the exact same problem as described under [Python: TIFFReadDirectory warning: unknown field with tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58279121/python-tiffreaddirectory-warning-unknown-field-with-tag): I get tons of annoying warnings from simply loading an image. The only difference is that I'm using `PyQt5` to read GeoTiff files. I tried to set up a warning filter, but can't get it right. Here is what I do:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
image = QtGui.QImage('PATH_TO_GEOTIFF')
```

The warning looks like

```
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag XXXXX (0xYYYY) encountered.
```

My filter attempt was:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

but it looks like PyQt does not throw a Python warning, but something weird to stdout that the `warnings` module does not catch. Or am I missing something really obvious here?

I don't know how to upload a working GeoTiff, in case someone tells me how to do that, I can add a test image.

---

UPDATE: I found the `libtiff-5.dll` in my local GIMP installation and was able to reference it the same way as in the linked question:

```
import ctypes
libbytiff = ctypes.CDLL(r"c:\Program Files\GIMP 2\bin\libtiff-5.dll")
libbytiff.TIFFSetWarningHandler.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]
libbytiff.TIFFSetWarningHandler.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
libbytiff.TIFFSetWarningHandler(None)
```

But the warnings still remain.

---

UPDATE 2: The only Qt-related `*tif.dll` I could find is `c:\Python310\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt5\plugins\imageformats\qtiff.dll`, but this immediately gives me `AttributeError: function 'TIFFSetWarningHandler' not found`.

Comment: Those are not PyQt warnings, but Qt ones.

Comment: @musicamante They aren't Qt warnings either: they're coming from the backend tiff library that is reading the image file.

Comment: @ekhumoro Yes, sorry, I wasn't clear, I meant that they are caused by the "Qt side" (which interacts with the library which finally outputs the warning)

Comment: That's already a good hint. How can I find out what library is being used, i.e. which DLL I need to reference (assuming the answer from the linked question might also work for me here)?

Comment: The ctypes solution seems to be the way to go. Normally [qInstallMessageHandler](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler) would be used to filter messages like this, but in this particular case, they're coming directly from the tiff library itself, so Qt doesn't see them.

Comment: @s6hebern Have you tried `libtiff.dll`? I suppose on Windows most libraries will be located under C:\Windows\System32.

Comment: Yes, I have located it within my GIMP installation and was able to reference it as given in the linked question, but still the same warning. Will edit my question to account for that try.

Comment: @s6hebern The Qt tiff plugin wouldn't be linked to a gimp lib: you need the system lib. I suggest using something like [Dependency Walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find the right dll.

Comment: Looks like I'm too dumb to figure out how to use it. On my other system, I found the `libtiff.dll` in the `OSGeo4W` directory, but whatever I try, the warnings don't go away. Probably I have to live with that.

Comment: @s6hebern You don't have to live with it. Clearly, Qt must link to *some dll*, otherwise QImage wouldn't be able to load tiff files. You just need to discover which specific one is being used. It is most likely to be in C:\Windows\System32. Have you tried searching in that folder for `*tiff*.dll` files? Alternatively, you can search using dependency walker by pointing it at the QtGui dll on your system (i.e. the one installed along with PyQt5).

Comment: PS: you could also try [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to see which dlls are loaded by a running Qt/PyQt program. There's also [ListDLLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/listdlls).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243657/discussion-between-s6hebern-and-ekhumoro).